XCode and OBS Virtual Camera
I use arm mac m1. Photo booth shows me two devices - my external USB camera and a virtual camera from OBS v30.1.2
I'm trying to get a list of capture devices in Xcode (15 and 16 beta).
I run my app on "My Mac (Designed for IPhone)" and only get a microphone.
Do you know how to get obs virtual camera in xcode?
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera;
AVCaptureDevice *backCamera;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {

    NSLog(@"Device name: %@", [device localizedName]);

    if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
            NSLog(@"Device position : back");
            backCamera = device;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Device position : front");
            frontCamera = device;
        }
    }
}

